# Discord Python Rewrite - JSON KeyError

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I want to make a permission System using JSON, but when I try to execute the code and I typed something in a chat, it raised `KeyError: 694446165197979670`.

My code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == True:
        pass
    else:
        with open('./perms.json', 'r') as f:
            perms = json.load(f)
        if message.author.id in perms:
            pass
        else:
            with open('./perms.json', 'r') as f:
                perms = json.load(f)
            perms[message.author.id]["owner"] = False
            perms[message.author.id]["admin"] = False
            with open('./perms.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(perms, f, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Full error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ideapad\Desktop\KAP-Revamp\Procfile\new.py", line 197, in on_message
    perms[message.author.id]["owner"] = False
KeyError: 694446165197979670
```

Comment: Presumably `'694446165197979670'` is not a key in `perms`. We can't tell you why or if it should be or not.

Comment: Note that you use both `message.author.id` directly, and its string representation, as key in `perms`. It should probably be only one of them.

Comment: @mkrieger1 wdym?

Comment: and yes, `'694446165197979670'` is not a key.

Comment: I mean that the integer `694446165197979670` is something different than the string `'694446165197979670'`, and your program is not consistent in which of the two it uses as a key in the `perms` dictionary.

Comment: @mkrieger1 but if i use `message.author.id` it raised a same error `KeyError: 694446165197979670`

Comment: full error message `Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ideapad\Desktop\KAP-Revamp\Procfile\new.py", line 197, in on_message
    perms[message.author.id]["owner"] = False
KeyError: 694446165197979670`

Comment: Why did you expect that the integer 694446165197979670 exists as a key in `perms`?